# Sorting a list alphabetically without sort method in python more efficiently

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm working on a python project where a string needs to be read from a file, sorted alphabetically, and written into another file.

I have a working program already, but it is inefficient and I would like to know how to improve it.

Here is my code:

```
def sorter(list):

    for i in range(len(list)):                                 
        for j in range(len(list) - 1 ):                         
            if list[j] > list[j + 1]:
               list[j], list[j + 1] = list[j + 1], list[j]     

    return list

def main():

    infile = open( 'text.txt', 'r' )   
    data = infile.read()               
    list = data.split()               

    newList = []                        
    for item in list:
        newList.append(item.lower())

    sorter(newList)                    

    with open( 'text2.txt', 'w' ) as f:  
        for item in newList:             
            f.write(" " + item)  

main()
```

Comment: Can you provide an example string that needs sorting, and what you expect the output of said example to be?

Comment: You could implement quicksort or mergesort.

Comment: can you use built in functions? sorted(list, key=str.lower)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `for i in range(...)` I don't see `i` used anythere else. Also you need to assign the output of sorter to newlist in your code, it's doing nothing right now.  Also what's the reason for adding a space to every line in the last for loop?

Comment: @Jaba He's writing a bubblesort, he just wants to do the operation in the `for j in range(...)` N times so that's why he has the `for i`. And he doesn't have to assign the output of sorter to newlist, sorter is modifying the list in place.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

Reading lines from a file can be done more succinctly just by using `f.readlines()` (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Separately you should `with` on both files so that you free up resources you no longer need:

```
def main():

    with open( 'text.txt', 'r' ) as infile:
        data = infile.read().split()

    with open( 'text2.txt', 'w' ) as f:  
        for item in sorted(data):
            f.write(" " + item)  

main()
```

This implementation, however, requires reading the entire file in memory. If you need to consume a truly massive amount (gigabytes) of data, you're probably better off with a more complicated approach.